# Why can't a MapView be instantiated with a specific spatialReference? (ArcGIS Javascript API 4.4)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm attempting to set the spatialReference property of the view to 102667. The console logs the error:

> init.js:321 [esri.views.MapView] The view could not be initialized
>   with the spatialReference 102667. Try specifying an extent or a center
>   and scale

I'm using the sandbox environment as an example, because I'm not understanding why this wouldn't work. The data I am working with is all projected with this spatial reference, so I thought it would be prudent to set the View to match. The excerpt comes from here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=get-started-mapview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Get started with MapView - Create a 2D map - 4.4</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.4/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.4/"></script>

  <script>
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map, MapView) {

      var map = new Map({
        basemap: "streets"
      });

      var view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        zoom: 4,
        center: [15, 65], // longitude, latitude
        spatialReference: {wkid: 102667}
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using an Esri basemap, the default spatial reference is [Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-SpatialReference.html#WebMercator), that is the reason the view could not be initialized with the spatialReference 102667.

You can try the following code:

```
<script>
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/geometry/SpatialReference",
  "esri/geometry/Extent",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, MapView, SpatialReference, Extent) {

  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets"
  });

  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    zoom: 4,
    center: [15, 65]
  });

  // Set the extent on the view
  view.extent = new Extent({
    xmin: -9177882,
    ymin: 4246761,
    xmax: -9176720,
    ymax: 4247967,
    spatialReference: new SpatialReference({wkid:102667})
  });

});
```

But my suggestion is either to use a basemap with your current Spatial Reference System, or to proyect your layers on the fly to the Web Mercator Spatial Reference.